# Not writing to log file when using pywinauto

Tags: python, logging, pywinauto, pywin

I am trying to automate some Windows action using [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io/), but when I `import pywinauto`, logging to the log file stops working.

Before importing - the code is writing the log the file, as in the following example:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', filemode='a', level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s",)
logging.info("Test")

.....
```

After importing - the code is **NOT** writing the log the file, as in the following example:

```
import logging
from pywinauto import application

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', filemode='a', level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s",)
logging.info("Test")

.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that `pywinauto` has its own usage of `logging` module.

In [`pywinauto/actionlogger.py`](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/actionlogger.py#L88), the code sets the logging level to `WARNING`, which disables writing of log messages under `WARNING` level (`INFO`, `DEBUG` and `NOTSET` levels) to the log file.

I have found a workaround to continue working with both `pywinauto` and `logging` - just importing `pywinauto` **after** the basic configuration of `logging`, instead of in the beginning:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', filemode='a', level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s",)

from pywinauto import application

logging.info("Test")

.....
```

This example works well - writes "Test" to the log file.